# CakePHP 3 $this->Model->get with conditions?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to modify a baked "view" function, since I need to check if the requesting user is the owner. This used to be very easy with CakePHP 2.x but I'm having some headaches with version 3.

This is the baked function:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $invoice = $this->Invoices->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);

    $this->set('invoice', $invoice);
}
```

Which is working perfectly, but as I said I'd like to add some conditions, like this

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $invoice = $this->Invoices->get($id, [
        'contain' => [],
        'conditions' => [
            'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
        ]
    ]);

    $this->set('invoice', $invoice);
}
```

The problem is that it just doesn't work. All I'm getting is

```
Error: Record "4" not found in table "invoices"
```

Why is that? How can I add that condition?

Comment: You could also try to use find() with first() or firstOrFail(), as this allows you a little bit more handling afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the documentation for Table::get()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_get):

> Returns a single record after finding it by its primary key, if no
>   record is found this method **throws an exception**.

I assume there is no record in the table present with the id 4 *AND* the user id you're passing to the conditions. Check that.

Comment: Damn you are right, I was looking for something that I didn't own. That exception message mislead me, but it was completely my fault. Thanks!